# Managing a connection to the mysql through a service

Tags: java, android, mysql, service

I got a service that generate the phone location.
I would like to send this string into my db but it's impossible through the service since I get a connection on main thread exception.
How should I do that?I would like to send the location every x time(probably a min).

I know how to connect to a mysql db and all around but I just don't know how to manage this system, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has nothing to do with the service itself.

The problem is that your operations are being executed on the UI thread, which is effectively stopping the UI from doing anything else.

The thread that calls the service life-cycle callbacks (`onStartCommand()`, `onBind()`, etc) is the UI thread.
You just have to fire it on an executor service, or a new thread, or depending on what you're implementing a [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) might be a handy class to use.

Comment: That's true since my screen freezes and then stop. My service is a subclass of service so should I just use a normal thread that will be started from the service that will do the mysql stuff operation?

Comment: the important is that you run it in a different thread. The most common ways is creating a new thread. But if you're doing a recurring work (every minute) you should check the Scheduled executor: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: Thanks, I will but what's bad in a  sub-class of a thread that sleeps for a minute?

Comment: 2 things: 1. You have no control over that "sleeps for a minute", 2. you're holding on to a resource doing nothing with it. An executor, allows you schedule when to run the threads, how many threads you want, quite a few direct methods to control the execution.