# NetworkOnMainThread Exception

Tags: java, android, service

I get this exception and I don't know why, that's the classes I have:
An activity which starts a service which starts a class which is a ScheduledExecutorService that connect to the db(that's why the connection thing).

When I tried to connect through my service I understood why I got this exception but now I created a new class/task to do that but I'm still getting this exception.

I didn't attached code since it's alot of code and the problem might be in the way I managed this system and not in the code itself, if you would like to see anything else let me know.

---

See [Managing a connection to the mysql through a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231703/managing-a-connection-to-the-mysql-through-a-service/14232064#comment19744504_14232064) for more information on why a `Thread` isn't appropriate in this case.

**EDIT**
code attachment:
this is my third class that sends details to the db.

```
public class SendLocation 
{
    private String lastAddress;
    private int id;
    private Connection conn;
    private PreparedStatement stmt;
    private LocationService ls1;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public SendLocation(int id,LocationService ls1)
    {
        this.lastAddress = "";
        this.id = id;
        this.conn = null;
        this.sqlConnect();
        this.sqlInsertStatement();
        this.ls1 = ls1;
    }
    public void send()
    {
        final Runnable sender = new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            { 
                if(!lastAddress.equals(ls1.getAddress()) && !ls1.getAddress().equals(""))
                {
                    lastAddress = ls1.getAddress();
                    try 
                    {
                        stmt.setInt(1, id);
                        stmt.setString(2, lastAddress);
                        stmt.execute();
                    } 
                    catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                }
            }
        };


        final ScheduledFuture sendHandle = 
                scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(sender, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        scheduler.schedule(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() 
            { 
                sendHandle.cancel(true); 
            }
        }, 60 * 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }



     public boolean sqlConnect()
        {
            try {
                Class.forName(Config.DRIVER).newInstance();
                DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(100);
                this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Config.URL+Config.DBNAME,
                        Config.USERNAME,Config.PASSWORD);
                return true;

            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
     public void sqlInsertStatement()
     {
         try {
             this.stmt = conn.prepareStatement
                     ("INSERT INTO locations(id, location) VALUES (?,?)");
         }catch (SQLException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
}
```

**EDIT**

I changed the task into a thread here is the new code:

```
public class SendLocation extends Thread
{
    private String lastAddress;
    private int id;
    private Connection conn;
    private PreparedStatement stmt;
    private LocationService ls1;
    private boolean run;

    public SendLocation(int id,LocationService ls1)
    {
        this.lastAddress = "";
        this.id = id;
        this.conn = null;
        this.sqlConnect();
        this.sqlInsertStatement();
        this.ls1 = ls1;
        this.run = true;
    }
    public void run() 
    { 
        while(run)
        {
            if(!lastAddress.equals(ls1.getAddress()) && !ls1.getAddress().equals(""))
            {
                lastAddress = ls1.getAddress();
                try 
                {
                    stmt.setInt(1, id);
                    stmt.setString(2, lastAddress);
                    stmt.execute();
                    sleep(1000);
                } 
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
        }
    }       
    public void destroy()
    {
        this.run = false;
    }
    public boolean sqlConnect()
    {
        try {
            Class.forName(Config.DRIVER).newInstance();
            DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(100);
            this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Config.URL+Config.DBNAME,
                    Config.USERNAME,Config.PASSWORD);
            return true;

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
     public void sqlInsertStatement()
     {
         try {
             this.stmt = conn.prepareStatement
                     ("INSERT INTO locations(id, location) VALUES (?,?)");
         }catch (SQLException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
}
```

How come now that I'm getting the NetworkOnMainThread exception??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception means that you are performing a long term operation on the UI thread, like a network operation eg. Since android 3, those operations are not allowed and the exception is thrown. So, in order to avoid the exception you should execute your code in a async way. You do not have to create class, but you have to create a class that extend `Thread` or `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I've been reccomanded not to use thread in that case.. :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231703/managing-a-connection-to-the-mysql-through-a-service/14232064#comment19744504_14232064

Comment: It looks like he recommended that you *do* use a thread. "the important is that you run it in a different thread"

Comment: Actually ScheduledExecutorService runs on a different thread. Probably you are run the wrong code inside the Runnable you submit as parameter. It is impossible, to say without see a snippet of your code

Comment: does the error happen in         this.sqlConnect() or
        this.sqlInsertStatement() ?

Comment: in the sqlConnect, the conn stays null.

Comment: try running both sqlConnect and sqlInsertStatement in an async way. It should fix the issue

Comment: I moved the code into a thread but it keeps giving me the same exception, please check the post again. Thanks.

Comment: The constructor does not run on a separate thread. The code inside the "run" method is executed on the a separate thread. You should create a class instance and call the start method.

Comment: Yes I did on the service class, I got an activity which starts my service and the service start this thread.

Comment: I see, but the constructor runs on the thread that creates the object

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! I moved the connection into the run method and it's working now! god bless you.

Answer (score 2):

you can Go through the Below Guide to solve out your problem.

> ```
>  android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
> ```

this error comes With **HoneyComb(3.0 or Later).**

**you can not perform a networking operation on its main thread as documentation says.** to getting ride of this you must use handler or asynctask. AFAIK There is no another way to do it.

you can See this for More Details [WHY ICS Crashes your App](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)

Try Using Below Code Snippet

```
new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        //do your Code Here    
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: But I do use a handler, check the post I updated it with code.

Comment: I tried also your idea with thread and I got the same result.